# Lint double comma arrays

Tags: javascript, lint, visual-studio-code

I have a question, about validating javascript file.
We have large javascript objects for configuring various things. Every so often one makes a mistake, where he enters double comma in an array, e.g.

```
config.items = [
    { foo: true },
    , { foo: false }
    , { foo: true }
]
```

This results in array like

```
[{...}, empty, {...}, {...}]
```

Funny enough, this could even be produced with typescript:

```
let items: string[] = ["", , "", ""];
```

And linter doesn't even bother about it.

My question is: what configuration and where I should set, to validate these kind of mistakes? As for configuration files, they are edited without full project, so no types would help. I need to help my configurator to setup his VSCode, so he can make valid edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using eslint there's the `no-sparse-arrays` option:

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-sparse-arrays

Comment: It would be helpful to say how to add that option to VSCode. I personally don't use it, so I don't know - I assume it's using ESLint (I think VisualStudio does by default) but I'm not sure where it picks up the config from - if it's looking at the project directory or do you need to manually supply it with configuration.